# remove content using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax.

I have **index.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"n.php",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").append(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>

<div id="div1" style="margin-left: 25;"></div>
<button>Add Author</button>
```

**demo.php**

```
Name:<input type="text" name="txtname">
age:<input type="text" name="txtage">
```

Above code adds name and age textboxes on index.html page when 'Add Author' button clicks without refreshing page.

Now I want to put another button 'remove author',and want to perform exact opposite action(i.e) remove Name and age textboxes which are added previously.

I don't know how to do this.Is it possible through something like this 
`$("#div1").(result);`

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
      <div id="div1" style="margin-left: 25;"></div>
      <button id="addAuthor">Add Author</button>
      <button id="removeAuthor">Remove Author</button>


 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#addAuthor").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({url:"n.php",success:function(result){
         $("#div1").html(result);
            }});
        });

        $("#removeAuthor").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var lastNode = $("#div1").children().last();
               lastNode.prev().remove();
               lastNode.remove();
         });
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Frst of all i want  $("#div1").append(result); not " html ".           And your code will empty the whole <div>.Is it possible to delete the content which was just previously loaded??

Comment: @Nirali Joshi please post what will be there inside `div` after loading what you are appending html tag ?

Comment: yes.but using  $("#div1").append(result); both the textboxes are added,how many time "Add Author" button was clicked..Now on click of remove author button.. i just want to remove last 2 textboxes.

Comment: Thanx for the help. but it is removing one by one textboxes.and label still remains.and I have more fields like textareas. so i want them all to remove on a single click.

Comment: I want it like  var lastNode = $("#div1:last"); But it is not working.

Comment: @NiraliJoshi : `$("#div1").children().last();` this will fix your problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27613/discussion-between-karthick-k-and-nirali-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$("#div1").empty()`, which will empty the div. Is that what you need?

Comment: $("#div1").append(result); will append both the textboxes as many times as the "Add author" button will click.Now what happens,$("#div1").empty() is emptying whole <div>.But i want to remove last two textboxes which was loaded just previously.Can u help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#remove").on("click",function(){
  $("#div1").empty();
});
});
```

Or use

`$("#div1").html("");` instead of `$("#div1").empty();`